# Slow Parallel.For interruption

Tags: .net, parallel-extensions

I have the following code inside a bigger loop, after profiling my code I discovered that all the Parallel.For gain in execution speed is lost in the long time the `Stop()` method takes to complete. Is there any way to improve this? Maybe calling `Thread.Sleep()`?

Thanks.

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000, (i, loopState) => 
{ 
   if (a == b)
       loopState.Stop(); 
});
```

Comment: Please add the code for the outer loop. Also bear in mind that Stop() might be waiting for all threads to join? (I'm guessing here).

Comment: That's not my experience, and in any case I would expect Parallel.For to be optimized for parallel execution and not fast cancellation.

Comment: What is your code doing? the piece you provided is useless. what are a and b, what is 1000? please post more code with description

Comment: @Brian: You are probably right, but in my scenario having to call the `loopState.Stop()` many times makes a big difference.

Comment: The outer loop is simply a - not parallel - for loop.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use `loopState.Break()` method, since it is paralel for `break` keyword. The `Stop` method sets `IsStopped` flag, so that other iterations may check this flag and stop at their convenience. It does not stop the loop.

See [Stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.stop.aspx) and [Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.break.aspx) on msdn

Comment: this is correct answer! Stop is cooperative, means that threads should stop manually if IsStopped returns true. Break is imperative for all and doesn't require cooperation.

Comment: Stop() should be faster as you can check here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782827.aspx

Comment: @devdept: May be, but you must write code to pool IsStopped flag for it to work. Break just works. Do no take sentences out of context.

Comment: @Andrey: Break will allow scheduled iterations to complete after it is called. Stop will allow running iterations to complete, but it will not schedule additional iterations after it is called.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen i am not sure that i understood the difference. could you explain?

Comment: @Andrey. Say you have a parallel loop that runs from 0 to 1000. If you break at index 100, Break will ensure that all iterations < 100 are completed before breaking. Stop on the other hand just stops the loop as early as possible.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen The only possible way to break "as early as possible" is to call Thread.Abort, i know no other ways to break executing code.

Comment: @Andrey. By "as early as possible" I meant "at the system's earliest convenience" as is the wording used by the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.break.aspx). The point being, that Break and Stop have very different semantics and that Break will actually allow further iterations to be scheduled.

Comment: Alternatively you can throw an exception - though not as clean